# neo4j EC2 AWS setup not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, neo4j, puppet

I'm trying to install neo4j on an EC2 instance and I tried following this setup:
http://www.neo4j.org/develop/ec2

Everything looks good, but when I go to the web panel, I get a page not found error. I went into the server and tried finding neo4j, but it's not installed. Does anyone know why it's not working?

Thanks

Comment: What's in /var/tmp/puppet.log?